# ActionScript - clicking and determining the sprite's class

Tags: actionscript-3, class, sprite

i'd like to add all or most of my mouse events to stage, but in order to do that i need to be able to tell what is the type of the sprite being clicked.

i've added two sprites to the display list, one of which is from a class called Square, the other from a class called Circle.

```
var mySquare:Sprite = new Square();
var myCircle:Sprite = new Circle();
addChild(mySquare);
addChild(myCircle);
```

now when i click on these sprites, i'd like to know from which class they are from, or which type of sprite it is.

```
//mousePoint returns mouse coordinates of the stage
var myArray:Array = stage.getObjectsUnderPoint(mousePoint());
if (myArray[myArray.length - 1] is Sprite)
...
```

so far i know how to do is determine if it *IS* a sprite display object, but since i'll only be working with sprites i need something more specific.  rather than checking "is Sprite", is there a way i can check "is Square" or "is Circle"?

```
if (myArray[myArray.length - 1] is Square)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've answered your own question.

```
if (myArray[myArray.length - 1] is Square)
```

If this doesn't work, then it should, so something else is wrong.

Comment: after reading the documentation, i was certain this would work.  you say it should, but it continues to return as false.  i don't know what possibly could be the cause of this.  any ideas?

Comment: oh i see what my problem is.  i was creating a sprite of type sprite within my class.